# How to format "for loop" for printing a (pseudo) code listing

Tags: algorithms

I want to write a 'for' statement, but unsure how to do this with LaTeX.  What I am trying to do is:

> for k = 1, k++, while k < i

What is the proper (or at least a decent way) to write this in LaTeX?

Let me re-phrase:

I do not want to actually create a loop, I just want to print a line that will be the text of the beginning of a for-loop.  I'm unsure how to do this.

Comment: We want to help you, but unsure how to help you as your statement is difficult to be parsed. Please provide a more detailed illustration.

Comment: Possibly you are looking for this: https://riptutorial.com/latex/example/28657/loops---repeating-things

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you just want to print the statement, then something like

```
\[
\text{for $k = 1$, $k{+}{+}$, while $k < i$}
\]
```

will set it in a displayed format (remember to call `\usepackage{amsmath}` in the preamble). If it's as an item in an `enumerate`, then

```
\item for $k = 1$, $k{+}{+}$, while $k < i$
```

is sufficient.

The only subtle point is to enclose the `+` symbols between braces, in order to avoid undesired spacings.

Answer (score 76):

If you're interested in *typesetting* algorithmic code, there are a number of choices. You can use a pseudocode environment `algpseudocode` offered by [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx). Here's a short example from the [`algorithmicx` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf) (with a pseudocode for loop added):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
      \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
        \State $a\gets b$
        \State $b\gets r$
        \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
      \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
      \For{\texttt{<some condition>}}
        \State \texttt{<do stuff>}
      \EndFor
      \State \Return $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

The [`algorithms` bundle](http://ctan.org/pgk/algorithms) supplied the `algorithm` floating environment.

Alternatively, the de-facto program typesetting package is [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings). The examples, usage and language support is vast. An abundance of examples is contained within the [`listings` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf).

Comment: For line `\State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}`, is there a reason you did not use the `\Return` keyword?

Comment: @ZaydH: There is no `\Return` defined by default.

Comment: maybe a dumb question -- but could you please explain more?  When I take the code you provided and change `\textbf{return}` to `\Return`, it compiles for me.  Is this going to be system specific? (I am running a very recent version of MacTex)  I am sure there is something I am missing and would like to understand more.

Comment: @ZaydH: If you look at the [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/algorithmicx) you'll see that I just copied the code from the first example listed. I briefly looked at the code of `algpseudocode.sty` and could see a `\Result`; I may have missed it. If it works now, that's fine.

Comment: @ZaydH: Just saw that `\Return` is defined within [`algpseudocode.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algpseudocode.sty).

Comment: Ok thank you for the clarification.  Given your score, I figured I was missing something.  Appreciate the extra check.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Time savior)

Answer (score 11):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H] 
\caption{Sum of Array Elements}
\label{alg:loop}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Require{$A_{1} \dots A_{N}$} 
\Ensure{$Sum$ (sum of values in the array)}
\Statex
\Function{Loop}{$A[\;]$}
  \State {$Sum$ $\gets$ {$0$}}
    \State {$N$ $\gets$ {$length(A)$}}
    \For{$k \gets 1$ to $N$}                    
        \State {$Sum$ $\gets$ {$Sum + A_{k}$}}
    \EndFor
    \State \Return {$Sum$}
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the package `algorithm2e`, we can rewrite the example provided above like the following in LaTeX:

```
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}    

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H] 
\SetKwInOut{Input}{input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
\Input{$A_{1} \dots A_{N}$}
\Output{$Sum$ (sum of values in the array)}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\caption{Sum of Array Elements}
\label{alg:loop}
\SetKwFunction{FLoop}{Loop}
\SetKwProg{Fn}{Function}{}{}
\BlankLine
\Fn{\FLoop{$A[\;]$}}{
  \State {$Sum$ $\gets$ {$0$}} \;
    \State {$N$ $\gets$ {$length(A)$}} \;
    \For{$k \gets 1$ to $N$} {
        \State {$Sum$ $\gets$ {$Sum + A_{k}$}}
    }
    \KwRet {$Sum$}
}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

with the following output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To the example given by Werner above. It did not work for me until I included braces as if I'm coding. Like this:

```
\For{\texttt{<some condition>}} {
        \State \texttt{<do stuff>}
      \EndFor
}
```

Comment: The syntax of [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) doesn't provide a second argument for `\For`. It only takes one argument. If you're using it this way, you're probably mixing [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e)'s syntax with `algorithmicx`'s constructions. Don't mix them - use one *or* the other.