# Algorithm not showing the end loop statement

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

I'm using `algorithm` package for writing algorithms. I'm using following code for generating a loop

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{My algorithm}\label{alg:myalgo}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Algo1}{}
\For{\texttt{<condition>}}
        \State \texttt{<my stuff>}
      \EndFor
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

This code on compilation gives the output

[image]

The problem with this output is it is not showing the `end for` after `line 3` as shown in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56871/how-to-format-for-loop) example.

Could someone tell me what is the problem with the above code.

Comment: Related: [`algpseudocode` without end block text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51295/5764)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The only reason for not having the "end for" is that you are using the `noend` option when loading `algpseudocode`.

In fact, the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{My algorithm}\label{alg:myalgo}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Algo1}{}
\For{\texttt{<condition>}}
        \State \texttt{<my stuff>}
      \EndFor
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

while, if you replace

```
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
```

with

```
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
```

you obtain

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this. Need `algpseudocode` package.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{My algorithm}\label{alg:myalgo}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Algo1}{}
\For{\texttt{<condition>}}
        \State \texttt{<my stuff>}
      \EndFor
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```